# Why do we write ABI before some functions

Tags: solidity, abi, abiencoderv2

Why do we write "abi" before abi.encode()? I understand that ABI is a like a JSON file used to help interaction of different applications because the solidity code is stored as bytecode, but I don't understand why we write "abi" before some "specific" functions in solidity.

I also know that abi.decode is a specific decoding function but why do we add "abi" before it. What is its usecase?
https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/units-and-global-variables.html#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mean: "Why do we have to put 'abi' into 'abi.encode()'?"

ABI encoding functions were [added in Solidity 0.4.24](https://medium.com/@libertylocked/what-are-abi-encoding-functions-in-solidity-0-4-24-c1a90b5ddce8) as a new feature.

Typing 'abi' before specific functions is intended as a way to easily identify those functions which deal with ABI encoding. It's just a design choice that the Solidity team made.

Comment: Thanks! I am coming from Java background and something with a '.' usually meant a package or class so I got confused. Thanks alot!